# Как сделать свою бд с IdentityDbContext?

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-mvc

Как правильно заполнять таблицу?
Создал Custom IdentityUser, создал AccountDatabase.mdf,  и вроде как создал правильный IdentityDbContex (все как в примере ниже)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name="Full Name"),Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Rang"), Required]
    public string Rang { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Обратите внимание, что authenticationType должен совпадать с типом, определенным в CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Здесь добавьте утверждения пользователя
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
public class AccountContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AccountContext() : base("AccountDatabase")
    { }
    DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    DbSet<SettingModel> SettingModels { get; set; }
}
```

, как правильно создать таблицу AccountDatabase? То при создании нового пользователя пишет:

```
Несколько наборов объектов на тип не поддерживаются. Наборы объектов "ApplicationUsers" и "Users" могут оба содержать экземпляры типа "ExampleCustomUserAndRole.Models.ApplicationUser".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вычеркните строку

```
DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

Она не нужна, т.к. вы уже указали что `AccountContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`.

"Заполнять" таблицу можете самым простым способом: регистрацией через сайт. Т.к. у вас все доп. поля (пока что) - это строки, то они просто будут пустыми.

По-хорошему, нужно конечно поправить контроллер AccountManager экшн Register который вызывается при регистрации пользователя. Хотя бы просто какими-то константами заполнить эти поля, либо поправить ввод данных полей в модели RegisterViewModel и представлении Register.cshtml.

Comment: А заполняется автоматически?

Comment: @A K, а еще не подскажите, чем бд у Migration отличается от app_data? То в инете инфы не нашел, а новый вопрос создавать нет желания через 40 минкь

Comment: @chilo5432 Ну... Задавайте хорошие вопросы - не будет question ban.

Comment: @A K, Я понял что "App_data is to store application data for the web process to acess", а Миграция это связь с БД? То есть если я хочу хранить сведения о пользователе надо использовать миграцию?

Comment: @chilo5432 Нет. App_data - это папка, где лежит база (посмотрите ваш ConnectionString  в конфиге). А миграция -- это разность между двумя схемами базы, описание как изменить одно состояние, чтобы получилось другое. Почитайте [какие-нибудь буквари по миграциям и EF](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/).

Comment: @A K, Больше спасибо за помощь